# !GCHandleLeaks "Didn't find 87 handles"

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

I analyze a memory dump with WinDbg to find a memory leak in my windows Service.

`!GCHandleLeaks` gives 87 handles.
I examine these handles with `!do poi(...)`.
Every handle leads to PresentationCore.dll.

Example:

```
Name:        <CppImplementationDetails>.LTSH_CONTROL$$BY0A@E
MethodTable: 000007fef3054580
EEClass:     000007fef2d07bb0
Size:        24(0x18) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll
Fields:
None
```

or

```
Name:        <CppImplementationDetails>.SBITLINEMETRICS_CONTROL$$BY0A@E
MethodTable: 000007fef3054028
EEClass:     000007fef2d07360
Size:        32(0x20) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll
Fields:
```

What does this mean?
What can i do further do find my memory leak?

Comment: Take memory profiler specially created for .net application

Comment: Does that number grow over time or not? Especially on native (C++) side, you might pass handles to the C++ part but they are not needed on the .NET side any more, so they *look* leaked, but are not.